# QS5026 - The variable cannot be reassigned here

Tags: quantum-computing, q#

I'm following tutorial from the official Microsoft learning page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/tutorial-qdk-explore-entanglement?pivots=ide-azure-portal) about quantum entanglement.

Basically, I copied an example posted there and I am getting error:

QS5026 The variable "numOnesQ1" cannot be reassigned here. In conditional blocks that depend on a measurement result, the target QuantinuumProcessor only supports reassigning variables that were declared within the block.

I understand what it says but it's just a copy from the official Microsoft tutorial. Am I missing something simple like imports, wrong settings? If not, how can I in other way set variables declared outside conditional blocks that depend on a measurement result?

Here is my code:

```
namespace Quantum.QuantumDream {

    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;

    operation GetRandomResult() : Result {
        use q = Qubit();
        H(q);
        return M(q);
    }

    @EntryPoint()
    operation TestBellState(count : Int, initial : Result) : (Int, Int, Int, Int) {
        mutable numOnesQ1 = 0;
        mutable numOnesQ2 = 0;

        // allocate the qubits
        use (q1, q2) = (Qubit(), Qubit());   
        for test in 1..count {
            SetQubitState(initial, q1);
            SetQubitState(Zero, q2);
    
            // measure each qubit
            let resultQ1 = M(q1);            
            let resultQ2 = M(q2);           

            // Count the number of 'Ones':
            if resultQ1 == One {
                set numOnesQ1 += 1;
            }
            if resultQ2 == One {
                set numOnesQ2 += 1;
            }
        }

        // reset the qubits
        SetQubitState(Zero, q1);             
        SetQubitState(Zero, q2);


        // Return number of |0> states, number of |1> states
        Message("q1:Zero, One  q2:Zero, One");
        return (count - numOnesQ1, numOnesQ1, count - numOnesQ2, numOnesQ2 );

    }

    operation SetQubitState(desired : Result, target : Qubit) : Unit {
        if desired != M(target) {
            X(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial code is only supposed to run on a local simulator (using `%simulate` magic commands in a Jupyter Notebook). From the error message, it looks like you've tried to run it on one of Quantinuum targets, which have some limitations on the kinds of things you can do in the code. To run equivalent code on Quantinuum, you'd need to define an operation for just the body of the loop (preparing a state and measuring it) and run it as a job - the cloud targets will take care of the loop themselves, running your code multiple times and returning to you a histogram of the results. For an example, you can see the QRNG sample in the samples gallery in Azure Portal.